# Log4J 1.2 SyslogAppender to detect fail connection

Tags: logging, udp, log4j, syslog

Currently I'm using log4j 1.2.x, and intend to use SyslogAppender for logging to syslog server. I have accomplish this.

However, I am aware that there is a possibility that the message does not received by the server. And I want to write the failed message/log to another file

So my questions are :

- Is it possible to detect failure on writing to Syslog server?
- If detection is out of question, is it possible to have a failover approach? As in SyslogAppender fail for any reason, FileAppender will be used instead.